# Why does a function $f$ is bounded on an interval $\Leftrightarrow f(x)=\underset{x\to a}O(1)$

Tags: approximation-theory

I just started a course on algorithm complexity and I tried to understand what was the **big-o** notation about. I think I understand it means a function is dominated by another, more simple. But what I don't understand is the following:

> A function $f$ is bounded on an interval $\Leftrightarrow f(x)=\underset{x\to a}O(1)$

$1$ will never dominate $x^2$, yet $x^2$ is has a lower bound...

Comment: $O(f)$ and $O(kf)$ is the same for a real $k$.

Comment: Since $f$ is bounded, $\lim \sup \frac{f}{1}$, $x \to a$ is bounded. Hence $f \in O(1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let me clarify the big-o notation. If $f(x)=O(g(x))$, then it means that $f(x)\leq c\cdot g(x)\,\forall x$.

Now, if the function is bounded, it means that it has *both a finite minimum and a finite maximum*. Say this maximum is $m$, at point (I assume) $x=a$. Since this is the maximum value the function can take, we have that

$$f(x)\leq m\,\forall x.$$

Furthermore, you can write $m$ as $m\cdot 1=O(1)$, so you end up having
$$f(x)=O(1).$$

Essentially, what this means is that the function can be upper-bounded in the interval of interest by a sufficiently high constant.